# Delete Local User Home Dir powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008

```
function deleteUsers($hash) {
   foreach ($h in $hash.GetEnumerator()) {
    Try
    {
        Remove-LocalUser -Name $($h.Name)
    }
    Catch{
        "Can't Delete User {0}" -f $($h.Name)
    }
   }
}

function createUsers($hash) {
   foreach ($h in $hash.GetEnumerator()) {

    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $($h.Value) –AsPlainText –Force
    New-LocalUser -Name $($h.Name) -Password $Password -AccountNeverExpires -FullName $($h.Name) -PasswordNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Users" -Member $($h.Name)
   }
}


$users = @{"User blabla" = "pass"; 
           "User blabla2" = "pass2"
        }

createUsers($users)
deleteUsers($users)
```

This basic powershell works fine but simply doesn't delete the user home directories, what should i add to deleteUsers function to fix this? I can't find an easy way to make it happen for Get-LocalUser. I only see solutions with Get-ADUser :/

I would love a solution on the same kind as below

```
$homeDir = Get-LocalUser -Name $($h.Name) -Properties HomeDirectory | Select -ExpandProperty HomeDirectory

    If (Test-Path $homeDir) 
    {
        Remove-Item -Path $homeDir -Force
    }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you want to delete a user locally from the PC, use `Remove-WmiObject`.  This ensures their registry, paths, etc. are removed.

Comment: The kind of standard tool for some years in this case is [Delprof2](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/).

Comment: thanks Olaf, but i wanted some builtin powershell, Remove-WmiObject doesn't look beautiful, but for powershell, i wasn't expected too much anyway ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend constructing the profile path as `"C:\\Users\\{0}" -f $h.Name` and then filtering `Win32_UserProfile` by that path. It's not guaranteed that a user's profile will always reside in `C:\Users\<username>`. Generally a better approach is:

1. Determine the user's SID:

   ```
   $name = 'someuser'
   $fltr = "name='${name}' and domain='${env:computername}'"
   $sid  = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter $fltr |
           Select-Object -Expand SID
   ```

   or

   ```
   $name = 'someuser'
   $acct = New-Object Security.Principal.NTAccount($name)
   $sid  = $acct.Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value
   ```
2. Use the SID to find and delete the profile:

   ```
   Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -Filter "sid='${sid}'" | ForEach-Object {
       $_.Delete()
   }
   ```
3. Delete the account:

   ```
   Remove-LocalUser -Name $name
   ```

   or (if you're running an older versin of Windows)

   ```
   ([adsi]'WinNT://.').Delete('user', $name)
   ```

In that order.

If you already deleted an account and need to remove the orphaned profile you can filter `Win32_UserProfile` for profiles with a reference count of zero:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -Filter 'refcount=0' | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Delete()
}
```

Also, note that `$profile` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) with the path to your [PowerShell profile](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx), so you shouldn't use that variable for other things.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to TheIncorrigible1, i finally end up doing this

```
function deleteUsers($hash) {
   foreach ($h in $hash.GetEnumerator()) {
    Try
    {
        Remove-LocalUser -Name $($h.Name)
        $pathUser = "C:\\Users\\{0}" -f "$($h.Name)" 
        $profile = GWMI -class Win32_UserProfile -Filter "LocalPath='$pathUser'"
        $profile.Delete()
        "[ OK ]User {0} deleted" -f $($h.Name)
    }
    Catch{
        "Can't Delete User {0}" -f $($h.Name)
    }
   }
}
```