# Delete folder with content exclude folder with content

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I need to write a script that deletes folders with last write time ~7 Days. But keep 2 "special" folder with the content in it.

Here's my script so far:

```
$source = "D:\TestOrdner"
$time = (Get-Date)#.AddDays(-7)

Start-Transcript "C:\log_files\log.txt"

gci $source -Recurse  | ?{$_.LastWriteTime -lt $time} | del -Force -Verbose

Stop-Transcript
```

My only problem is how to EXCLUDE the folders with content?
My folder to keep: `D:\TestOrdner\Test`.

Comment: Does the folder you want to exclude contain subfolders that also shouldn't be deleted?

Comment: Yes, the folder I dont want to delete, contains files, subfolders with files. FYI it's a Profilefolder.

Comment: basically if you have any files in the folder, you should not delete that folder and if there any files in the folder you should delete it? Is that right?

Comment: From the Start: C:\Users -> 10 Profile folders. Every Folder with a LastWriteTime -7days should be deleted. But 2 Profilefolders (Administrator and Public) shouldnt be deleted, even if there older then 7 days. And all of the folders got subfolders and files etc.

Comment: Do you want to delete the entire profile folders or just stuff inside the profiles that is older than 7 days?

Comment: I want to delete the entire Profilefolder that is older than 7 days.

Comment: I think you also do not want to delete the hidden folder `Default` from which new user profiles are built.

Comment: Don't delete user profiles in the filesystem unless you have a good reason to do so. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48386318/1630171) for how to properly delete user profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when deleting user profile folders, so keep the `-WhatIf` switch until you are **absolutely sure** the below will not delete folders that should not be deleted.

It might be a good idea to `Move` these folders instead of deleting them?

Since this concerns a user profile folder where every user has his/her own folder directly under the root folder, there is no need for the `-Recurse` switch on `Get-ChildItem`

Anyhow, this should do it:

```
$source    = "D:\TestOrdner"
$time      = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)

Start-Transcript "C:\log_files\log.txt"

Get-ChildItem $source -Directory -Exclude 'Administrator','Default','Public' | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $time} | 
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -confirm:$false -WhatIf

Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: I didnt had Time to check it, but thanks! I will check as soon as I can!